# Construction of a triple cover of $A_6$ in "Finite Simple Groups" by Wilson

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading [The Finite Simple Groups](http://books.google.com.ar/books?id=lYMAg_Sj7hUC&lpg=PR9&pg=PA29#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Robert Wilson: see page 29. I want to understand a construction of triple cover of $A_6$. On section 2.7.3., I don't understand the second paragraph, which is following:

> In addition to the above ... i.e. the map..

Could someone clarify this?

Given vectors $(0,0,1,1,1,1), \ (0,1,0,1,\omega, \omega^2)$, if I take the multiples of $\omega $ and $\omega^2$ and map them under $S_4$ as said in the first paragraph, I understand that one gets a set of 45 vectors.

Now, my questions are:

1) What does monomial elements mean? There is given an example but what are others?

2) In the third paragraph, he says "This group....". What is he referring to? How do we get $G$?

ADDED: Why does $G$ induce all even permutations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "Monomial element" refers to a monomial matrix; a matrix with exactly one non-zero entry in each row and column (also known as a generalised permutation matrix, cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix)). But in the paragraph you're reading it is enough to take the bracketed sentence to be the definition (i.e. a monomial matrix is a product of a permutation matrix with a diagonal matrix).
2. "This group" refers to the group generated by all the symmetries considered so far, i.e. the coordinate permutations $S_{4}$ and the "other monomial elements".

Comment: Thanks! In your part 1) I assume that in a monomial matrix, permutation matrix would come from $S_4$ as described in the paper. What about diagonal matrices? In part 2) I don't see how one arrives $G$ (which should have order 1080). So, as I understand, $G$ consists of $S_4$ and other monomial elements. That is # of monomial elements should be $1080-24=1056$. Correct? But how does one arrives at this fact so easily? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: My previous comment was slightly off, so this is a rewording. It's not true that the monomial matrices used are  products of things in $S_{4}$ with a diagonal matrix. For example, the given element is $(1,2,3)\text{diag}(1,1,1,1,\bar{\omega},\omega)$, but $(1,2,3)$ does not lie in the given copy of $S_{4}$. The paragraph is only saying that: In addition to $S_{4}$, there are other monomial matrices which preserve the set of 45 vectors.

Comment: (continued) we let $G$ be the whole group of such things, so $G$ contains $S_{4}$ and the given monomial matrix. We get the size of $G$ by noticing that $G$ has a surjection to $A_{6}$ and finding the kernel of this surjection.

Comment: Few more questions: 1) If a monomial is a product of a permutation and a diagonal matrix, where will permutation matrix come from and what will be the entries in diagonal matrix? Do we consider permutation matrices from $S_6$? 2) How do we know that $G$ will induce all even permutations, when it acts on 6 co-ordinate positions?

Comment: 1) A $6 \times 6$ monomial matrix will be a product of a permutation matrix of degree $6$ (i.e. something from $S_{6}$) and a diagonal matrix. The paragraph doesn't say that *all* such matrices will work. 2) The fact that $G$ induces all even permutations can be shown in the same way as the "routine exercise" mentioned: For example if you check that each 3-cycle is induced by $G$, then $G$ induces whole alternating group.

Comment: I am sorry, but monomial element in this context seems to be extremely vaguely defined. How does one know which permutation matrix from $S_6$ to include, which ones to exclude, if all doesn't work? Also, what will be the entries in a diagonal matrix? Any combination of $1,\omega, \omega^2$?

Comment: One way to think of it is: We define $G$ to be exactly those monomial elements which preserve the set of 45 vectors. There's nothing vague about this bit: In principle we could go through all permutation matrices in $S_{6}$ and all diagonal matrices and see which ones perserve the set of 45 vectors. It's clear that the diagonal matrices can only have entries from $\{1,\omega,\omega^{2}\}$, otherwise we'd get other scalars appearing in the vector coordinates.